# How to remove empty elements from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following array named `parsedAutor` and I need to remove the empty elements from the nested arrays.

```js
[
  ['John Doe', '', 'CPF 000.000.000-00'],
  ['30/05/2018 - Vara de Delitos de Roubo e Extorsão'],
  ['John Doe', '', 'CPF 000.000.000-00'],
  ['29/02/2016 - 1ª Vara Criminal'],
  ['John Doe', '', 'CPF 000.000.000-00'],
  ['18/02/2016 - 3º Juizado Especial Cível'],
  ['John Doe', '', 'CPF 000.000.000-00'],
  ['18/02/2016 - 3º Juizado Especial Cível']
]
```

How do I manage to do it? I've been trying to map the elements and then filter them, but it's not working and I think I'm doing it wrong.

Here's what I've been trying to do.

```js
const autor = $('div[class="espacamentoLinhas"]').toArray();

let parsedAutor = autor.map((x) => x.children[2].data.trim());

console.log(parsedAutor);

parsedAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => x.split('\n').map((y) => y.trim()));

console.log(parsedAutor);

// note that the code above is just to get the context from where I taking the values,  please focus on the code below

const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => {
  x.filter((y) => y !== '');
});

console.log(filteredAutor);
```

But it returns me eight `undefined` values, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have only strings or arrays inside?

Comment: obviously you could change the splitting part to allow more multiple empty lines.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question, keep in mind that according to Brazilian law(And common sense), you should not expose the CPF numbers and person names, when asking questions, always use mock values.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need return the filter on x, or shorten it. return a value from your map() callback, either by using the return statement or removing the braces to make it an expression arrow function.

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => x.filter((y) => y !== ''));
```

or

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => {
    return x.filter((y) => y !== '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct! You need to return the filter on x, or shorten it.

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => x.filter((y) => y !== ''));
```

Or

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => {
    return x.filter((y) => y !== '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value from your `map()` callback, either by using the `return` statement or removing the braces to make it an expression arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the value from `map`.

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map((x) => {
   return x.filter((y) => y !== '');
});
```

Or else just do

```
const filteredAutor = parsedAutor.map(x => x.filter(y => y !== ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this one ?

```js
let myDoubleArray = [ [ 'Gladson de Lima Cameli', '', 'CPF 434.611.072-04' ]
                    , [ '30/05/2018 - Vara de Delitos de Roubo e Extorsão' ]
                    , [ 'Gladson de Lima Cameli', '', 'CPF 434.611.072-04' ]
                    , [ '29/02/2016 - 1ª Vara Criminal' ]
                    , [ 'Gladson de Lima Cameli', '', 'CPF 434.611.072-04' ]
                    , [ '18/02/2016 - 3º Juizado Especial Cível' ]
                    , [ 'Gladson de Lima Cameli', '', 'CPF 434.611.072-04' ]
                    , [ '18/02/2016 - 3º Juizado Especial Cível' ]
                    ]
// remove empty elements

for (let inArr of myDoubleArray)
  {
  for(let i = inArr.length;i--;) {  if (inArr[i]==='') inArr.splice(i,1)  }
  }

console.log(myDoubleArray)
```